# How to replace draggable canvas with a JPEG image in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

**Code**

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.state('zoomed')


def drag(event):
    event.widget.place(x=event.x_root, y=event.y_root,anchor=CENTER)



card = Canvas(root, width=50, height=50, bg='blue')
card.place(x=300, y=600,anchor=CENTER)


card.bind("<B1-Motion>", drag)


root.mainloop()
```

**Question**

Instead of the movable blue square, How can I replace it with a specific JPEG image file?

But without giving it width and height, whatever the height and width of the image is, keep it as it is.

What I mean by that is, automatically load the image with it's original size

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `Label` widget:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.state('zoomed')

def drag(event):
    event.widget.place(x=event.x_root, y=event.y_root,anchor=CENTER)

pic = PhotoImage(file="pic_file_name")

label = Label(root,image=pic)
label.place(x=300, y=600,anchor=CENTER)
label.img = pic

label.bind("<B1-Motion>", drag)

root.mainloop()
```